# How does the shield around Wakanda work?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

How come the first spaceship was completely blocked by the shield around Wakanda while some of the alien creatures passed through in *Avengers: Infinity War*?

Comment: It works very well, thank you for asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The shield seems to work against blocking initial impacts against it but can't cope against a sustained force and it begins to break down. Note even against the Outriders it blocks their initial attack into it but as they keep pushing and forcing against it they manage to get through.

Check out the below image and the noted points.

1. An Outrider is pressing against the barrier and is starting to break it down.
2. An Outrider has been pressing against the barrier for a while and starts to push itself through
3. An Outrider has just hit the barrier; the pulse ripples along the barrier but it doesn't break.

[image: A burnt Outrider screams as it's just broken through the barrier, several others in the background attempt to join it as others lay dead around it in the grass]

So, whilst the barrier can block the initial energy thrown against it, it does no good against a sustained force that the Outriders are able to apply to it.

Comment: *The Outriders continued to pour from the ships and threw themselves against the shield. They climbed on top of the bodies of their fallen and tried to force their way through the energy barrier, despite losing limbs and dying in the process. Okoye stared in horror, standing by the Black Panther's side. "They're killing themselves." What she couldn't bring herself to say was that one by one, however slowly, they were breaking through Wakanda's defenses.* - From the novelisation