# How did Bifrost breach the force field?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In Avengers: Infinity War, we see that the Alien spaceships trying to enter Wakanda were met with a force field, which completely destroyed the ship.

How then was the Bifrost able to breach the force field and take Thor, Groot and Rocket to Wakanda?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/236707

Comment: The Bifrost is completely different to spaceships and aliens, the comparison between the two doesn't really work. It managed to get through because it works completely different and is strong enough to break through

Comment: The question my question has been tagged as a duplicate of does not have a very good answer, it blatantly claims it's because of Bifrost being very powerful which imho not a sufficient answer

Comment: It having a bad answer does not negate it being a dupe (unfortunately).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, any suggestions what I should do from a highly ranked and long time member of this community i.e you?

Comment: The usual suggestion when you want to ask a question but find it has already been asked but the answers are lacking is to bounty the existing question.

Comment: A different tack would be to consider why you believe that it's implausible that Asgardian technomagic is insufficient to the task of penetrating (advanced but still) Earthly technology?  Physical ships going splat against a shield designed to stand against physical threats is one thing.  Matter transmission is something else entirely.  Why would you think the Wakandan shields would be optimized against something they've literally never before had to defend against?

Comment: The Bifrost "portal" exists outside of our universe's space and time.  It's noteworthy that Stormbreaker, built to include the Bifrost power, effortlessly passes through the barrier that Thanos attempts to block it with - because Thanos, using the infinity stones, only has power over *this universe's* space and time.  And the animation showing it doing so duplicates the Bifrost animation.  (These claims would be hard to prove, so I am making them in a comment rather than as an answer.)

Comment: @tbrookside we see the Bifrost travelling through space and time at the start of Endgame with Banner. And we see it land numerous times. Unless you're claiming the internals of the Bifrost exist outside of space and time but then I doubt that would be the case.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The Bifrost supplies nearly instantaneous travel between any two points.  The only other travel method in the MCU that is remotely comparable (while still inferior) is wormhole jumping.  Anyone traveling by Bifrost is outside of "normal" space and time while doing it.  No other "handwave" of what is happening fits.

Comment: @tbrookside Well you're assuming real life physics for something that is clearly not real life or has ever been explained. It certainly doesn't exist outside of space and time in the traditional sense at least because we see it in space and time numerous times.